# How to wait multiple CompletionToken using C++20 coroutine with Boost.Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, coroutine, asio

## Background

I'm using Boost.Asio. I call multiple asynchronous functions, then I want to wait multiple CompetionToken. For example, `async_read()` and `steady_timer::async_wait()`.

I implemented it using Boost.Asio's stackless coroutine. It works fine.

There are two timers. The first timer is longer time then the second one. So the second timer is fired earlier, and cancel the first timer.
The first timer is an emulation of `async_read()`, and the second timer is its timeout.

### Stackless coroutine approach

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;

#include <boost/asio/yield.hpp>

template <typename Executor>
struct my_app {
    my_app(Executor exe)
        :exe_{std::move(exe)},
         worker_{*this}
    {}

private:
    friend struct worker;
    struct worker {
        worker(my_app& ma)
            :ma_{ma}
        {
            // initiate coroutine
            (*this)(boost::system::error_code{}, std::string{});
        }
        void operator()(
            boost::system::error_code const& ec,
            std::string timer_str // to distinguish timer
        ) const {
            reenter(coro_) {
                std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

                yield {
                    // set two timers
                    // timer1 is a kind of receive emulation 
                    // timer2 is a receive timeout
                    ma_.t1_.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
                    ma_.t1_.async_wait(
                        as::append(
                            *this,
                            "timer1"
                        )
                    );
                    ma_.t2_.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
                    ma_.t2_.async_wait(
                        as::append(
                            *this,
                            "timer2"
                        )
                    );
                }
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << timer_str << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << timer_str << " fired" << std::endl;
                    if (timer_str == "timer2") {
                        ma_.t1_.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        my_app& ma_;
        mutable as::coroutine coro_;
    };

    Executor exe_;
    as::steady_timer t1_{exe_};
    as::steady_timer t2_{exe_};
    worker worker_;
};

#include <boost/asio/unyield.hpp>

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;
    my_app ma{ioc.get_executor()};
    ioc.run();
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xM8o4Yzfa

## How to implement the same logic using C++20 coroutine ?

I tried to migrate from the stackless coroutine to C++20 coroutine. But I couldn't find a way to wait multiple CompletionToken. How should I do ?

### What I tried

#### use co_await step by step

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;

template <typename Executor>
as::awaitable<void>
proc(Executor exe) {
    as::steady_timer t1{exe, std::chrono::milliseconds{200}};
    as::steady_timer t2{exe, std::chrono::milliseconds{100}};
    // how to multiwait t1 and t2 ?
    co_await t1.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "timer fired1" << std::endl;
    co_await t2.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "timer fired2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;
    as::co_spawn(ioc, proc(ioc.get_executor()), as::detached);
    ioc.run();
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zjT8W6Wxr

It doesn't work well because after t1 is fired the second timer is set.

#### use multiple co_spawn

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;

as::awaitable<void>
proc1(as::steady_timer& t1) {
    try {
        co_await t1.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "timer1 fired" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const& ec) {
        std::cout << "timer1 " << ec.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

as::awaitable<void>
proc2(as::steady_timer& t1, as::steady_timer& t2) {
    try {
        co_await t2.async_wait(as::use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "timer2 fired" << std::endl;
        t1.cancel();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const& ec) {
        std::cout << "timer2 " << ec.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;

    as::steady_timer t1{ioc.get_executor(), std::chrono::seconds{2}};
    as::steady_timer t2{ioc.get_executor(), std::chrono::seconds{1}};

    as::co_spawn(ioc, proc1(t1), as::detached);
    as::co_spawn(ioc, proc2(t1, t2), as::detached);

    ioc.run();
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jba7dsYcx

It is technically possible but still have problems. For example, this approach cannot seems to work in the awaitable function (the function has return value `as::awaitable<T>`).
I guess that there are better ways.

## Environment

Boost 1.83.0
x86-64 clang 17.0.1

Comment: Haven't tried myself but this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230710-00/?p=108405) seems worth reading.

Comment: Side note: You're not awaiting CompletionTokens. You're awaiting `awaitable<>`s

Comment: @sehe, thanks. Let me clarify my understanding. I pass `use_awaitable` to async_function. When async process is finished, the CompletionToken is invoked and returns `awaitable<>`. So I need to treat well the two `awaitable<>`s, not CompletionTokens. CompletionTokens have already been invoked. Am I understanding correctly ?

Comment: Close. `use_awaitable` is the completion token. It is used during _initiation_ to produce a _handler_ which gets invoked on completion. `awaitable` encapsulates a coro frame. `co_await` transforms the `awaitable`'s promise to _resume_ the coro when _handler_ is invoked. Read more here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html#boost_asio.reference.asynchronous_operations.completion_tokens_and_handlers

Comment: I'm interested in very subtle point the difference between Completion token and Completion handler. use_awaitable and use_future are Completion token. It is OK. And aync operation produces corresponding Completion handler on initiatiing. It is OK.
In the case I pass lambda expression or function/function object to async function, which term should I use? They are Completion handler so no producing process happens? or They are also Completion token and puroduce process is just copy/move ?

Comment: In that case the token itself is indeed the handler. In a way, the callback-style is the fundamental building block for all async operations, all other completion token mechanisms are implemented in terms of handlers. You can read the code or ask your compiler these questions: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/850d57d6c2c20b8d It confirms everything you've just said. TBH it could have been a nice Stackoverflow question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asio implements parallel groups, in a similar vein to the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230710-00/?p=108405) post [commented by Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657603/how-to-wait-multiple-completiontoken-using-c20-coroutine-with-boost-asio#comment136909255_77657603):

[Coordinating Parallel Operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/parallel_group.html)

Though technically "experimental" this functionality is clearly here to stay. The `experimental` nature indicates that some aspects of its API interface or semantics might still change slightly¹.

The documentation shows how to work with them:

> The conditions for completion of the group may be specified using one of the four provided function objects `wait_for_all`, `wait_for_one`, `wait_for_one_success`, `wait_for_one_error`, or with a custom function

However since you're dealing with awaitables, ***by far*** the most convenient way to benefit from parallel operations is by using [`awaitable_operators`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.co_ordinating_parallel_coroutines):

```
asio::awaitable<void> both() {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    asio::steady_timer t1{ex, 200ms};
    asio::steady_timer t2{ex, 100ms};

    co_await (t1.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable) && t2.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable));
    std::cout << "both completed" << std::endl;
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8aa99f1ad343aee)**.

> *Note how the executor is intrinsic to the coroutine.*

Things become slightly more interesting with output, variadics, non-exception error propagation etc.:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3365812f0d1a378f)**

```
using Timer = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<asio::steady_timer>;
using Task  = asio::awaitable<void>;

Task all(auto... duration) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;

    auto task = [ex](auto duration) -> Task {
        co_await Timer(ex, duration).async_wait();
        std::cout << "completed: " << duration << std::endl;
    };

    co_await (task(duration) && ...);
    std::cout << "all completed" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    co_spawn(ioc, all(100ms, 200ms, 50ms, 2s), asio::detached);
    ioc.run();
}
```

Which you might prefer without the lambda:

```
Task task(auto duration) {
    co_await Timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, duration).async_wait();
    std::cout << "completed: " << duration << std::endl;
};

Task all(auto... duration) {
    co_await (task(duration) && ...);
    std::cout << "all completed" << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
completed: 50ms
completed: 100ms
completed: 200ms
completed: 2s
all completed
```

Conversely:

```
Task any(auto... duration) {
    co_await (task(duration) || ...);
    std::cout << "first completed" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cd2f58483031d82)**

```
completed: 50ms
first completed
```

And getting some results at the same time:

```
template <typename Duration> asio::awaitable<Duration> task(Duration dur) {
    co_await Timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, dur).async_wait();
    co_return dur;
};

Task any(auto... dur) {
    using M = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    std::array<M, sizeof...(dur)> args{dur...};

    auto r = co_await (... || task(dur));
    std::cout << "Completed: #" << r.index() << "/" << args.size() << ", " << args.at(r.index()) << std::endl;

    assert(std::visit<M>(std::identity{}, r) == args.at(r.index()));
}
```

Printing **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46e4eec0d4382077)**

```
Completed: #2/4, 59ms
```

---

¹ I'm not accutely aware of any such changes over the last ~5 release

Comment: thank you for the answer. It seems that `make_parallel_group()` and `wait_for_one()` would solve my issue. I need to know which timer is fired and need to cancel the other timer (Actual case is a combination of some async function and its timeout timer). Anyway I will study about your answer.

Comment: As you can see my last example does all that: it knows which timer completed, gets the returned value (as a variant) **and** all the other operations in the parallel group have been canceled. If you actually *run* the example you will see that the total program runs in 50ms, not 2s. I see now that I have a BUG in printing the duration, because the result is not a flat variant. Let me fix that...

Comment: Now [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77659204/revisions), see **[Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46e4eec0d4382077)**

Comment: now I noticed that `co_await` with `||` operator. It is simpler. By the way, I couldn't find a document about `awaitable_operators`. Could you tell me a link of the document?

Comment: I found `awaitable_operators` documents 
https://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_22_2/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.co_ordinating_parallel_coroutines

Comment: Yes. Added a [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.co_ordinating_parallel_coroutines) to the answer :)

Comment: Nice! It is in the Boost Library document.